# I couldn't submit my edit on an answer due to unformatted code, yet I didn't edit any code in the answer. Why?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, edits, rejected-edits

I recently went to edit [a popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/9808974) because a certain sentence made some physics references that were worded somewhat awkwardly (at least to me), so I reworded the sentence and hit submit without editing anything else.  My submission wasn't allowed because of improperly formatted code.  Why did this happen?

Screenshot of edited portion with error:
[image]

Original text:[image]

Comment: I was just able to edit it to remove redundant alt text so I wasn't able to duplicate your issue.

Comment: @BSMP Try making the exact edits that I made, then see if you can replicate the issue

Comment: Edit before 2K doesnt follow the same rules as edit >2K. Because our edit goes to suggestion. You will have the same issue for question that is only code but shape to be text instead of codeblock. Any try to edit will trigger bad format or code only notification.

Comment: Best solution is either go for an other edit. Or if there is real value, comment or chat about it. And reach 2k+

Comment: FWIW: I have read the given branch prediction failure answer several times and I think the edit you attempted actively harms the readability of that sentence, objects don't *move with* inertia, they *have* inertia, and the use of *large time period* is very strange, better would've been to use *long time*, but at that point why not leave it as *forever*?

Comment: @NickA If they took _forever_ to start up, trains would never move, right?

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri Forever just means a very long time in this context, it's common place to use it like this in english, see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/whats-the-meaning-of-take-forever)

Comment: I've had this bug happen to me but assumed it was because i used the asterixes

Comment: @Jodast I concur with Nick A; your edit there would've served to make the answer worse. To me, it reads well in very simple language, and your edit makes it broken and confusing.

Comment: If anything, I would've just gone with "really long" instead of "forever" or whatever else. And probably "start moving" instead of "start up" (the latter sounds like you're referring to starting the engine as opposed to starting to move).

Comment: aren't most of your comments a bit beside the point? (edit. and I'm not speaking about OP)

Comment: @eis yeah they kinda are

Comment: SE unformatted code detection is not really reliable and doesn't work all the time. It's not like that SE devs want to explain the implementation details, so this question can't be answered. As a workaround ask someone >2K to edit it if it's useful (as mentioned above)

Comment: @eis aren't most of your comments a bit beside the point? - Almost always in meta

Answer (score 2):

This was tested and does not appear to be an issue any longer. I've updated the status to completed.